# How could I do bindParam with LIKE?

Tags: php

I'm trying create a LIKE using `bindParam`. When I try execute it does throws an exception.

How could I do it?

```
public function getLocalByNome($nomeLocal){
        $stm = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM locais WHERE nome LIKE ?");
        $stm->bindParam(1, "%".$nomeLocal."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->execute();
        $lista = $stm->fetchAll();

        return $lista;
    }
```

Exception:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /opt/lampp/htdocs/TelefonesUteis/dao/LocalDAO.php on line 94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

```
$tempString = "%".$nomeLocal."%";
$stm->bindParam(1, $tempString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or

```
$stm->bindParam(1, $tempString = "%".$nomeLocal."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This error is thrown because you are binding a variable where as you can say

```
$stm->bindParam(1, $tempString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$tempString = 'something else';
```

and when you execute the statement it will use `something else` even though you set it after binding it to the pdo statement.